# How can I group-by a Dataframe to get repeated values as a list for a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

After querying a DB I get a Dataframe like this:

```
   Animal      Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
```

As can be seen, Animal column has repeated values and I wanna group that column and get as result (it doesn't matter if the result is in a diff data type, like dict):

```
   Animal      Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0, 370.0
1  Parrot       24.0, 26.0
```

All the examples I've seen so far for `df.groupby(['column_name'])` has another operation (like `sum(), count()`) but what I need is to have only one entry along with all the values.

Is there any operation that can be used to perform this change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {"Animal": ["Falcon", "Falcon", "Parrot", "Parrot"], "Speed": [123, 235.2, 323, 223.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["Speed"] = df.Speed.apply(lambda x: str(x))
df['CT_Speed'] = df.groupby(['Animal'])['Speed'].transform(lambda x : ', '.join(x))
df.drop("Speed", axis=1, inplace = True)
df = df.drop_duplicates()

df
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of aggregation to a `pd.Series` with each cells containing a `list` of values:

```py
data = {"Animal": ["Falcon", "Falcon", "Parrot", "Parrot"], "Speed": [380.0, 370.0, 24.0, 26.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
serie = df.groupby(["Animal"])["Speed"].agg(lambda x : x.tolist())

serie
```

It should output :

```sh
Animal
Falcon    [380.0, 370.0]
Parrot      [24.0, 26.0]
Name: Speed, dtype: object
```